# How to send a numeric value via ssh to the raspberry pi console

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, keyboard-input

So I already have a SSH connection working but I'm looking for a command that can write a number like '1' into the console on the raspberry pi.

Thanks Sabifa

Comment: Do you want to display "1" on the pi's display? Or do you want to simulate the user typing "1"?

Comment: Hi, I want to simulate the user typing 1. Just like a keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried echoing it out to your terminal?

```
    echo 1 > /dev/pts/0
```

Remember that (just about) everything has a device file, that can be redirected to. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for that it worked! Do you know if it can automatically press enter after the 1? I´m a real noob in this ssh communication thing^^

Comment: Could you one up my answer please? I am trying to gain enough credits to hit 15! Many thanks and glad i answered your question.

Comment: Sabifa, what are trying to do? It will probably be much easier to write it into a script and automate when it run.

Comment: I have a led game running on my pi. This game needs User Inputs. For now, I give the inputs via a keyboard Input but with the iot a Smartphone control for this game would be nice. My program is used to do something If the numbers from 1 to 9 are pressed. So I thought it would be the easiest way to send a number, ie. a one via something like a ssh connection.